# Перевести формулу на c

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Есть формула из wolframalpha.com , в которой 100500 символов, в т.ч. знаки степени ("^"). Язык C, насколько я знаю, их не понимает, ему pow(,) подавай.

Пробовал вручную все переделать - без ошибок не обходится. Есть какой-нибудь автоматизированный метод?

Comment: Было бы очень неплохо, если бы Вы показали саму формулу - ссылку на wolframalpha туда, где она есть.

Comment: Формула - это просто решение биквадратного уравнения:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a*x%5E4%2Bb*x%5E3%2Bc*x%5E2%2Bd*x%2Bk%3Df

P.S.Мне нужны только действительные корни.

Comment: Еще вопрос: как Вы с С пишите выражение "1/3" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовать преобразовать через регулярное выражение. Можно в несколько проходов.

upd:
Копируете формулу в notepad++ или в другой редактор, поддерживающий рег. выражения. жмете Ctrl+H, пишите что заменить, на что заменить, выбираете рег. выражения. Например искать `(\d+)\^(\d+)`, заменить на `pow(\1,\2)` найдет в строке все выражения `число1^число2` и заменит их на `pow(число1,число2)`. Подробнее про описание рег. выражений в гугл.

Comment: А можно по-подробнее?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: тут можно ещё больше ошибок наделать.

Comment: Для этого существует комбинация клавиш Ctrl+Z и создание копий промежуточных результатов.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но я спрашивал про автоматизированный метод=) А тут все ручками надо делать. Vladimir VG +1.

Comment: Здесь нужно 1 раз ручками написать рег. выражение. Это не менее автоматизировано чем 1 раз ручками написать программу, которая в дальнейшем автоматизирует некоторую работу.

Comment: Эта задача ближе к лексическому разбору, чем регэкспу. Представляю себе сколько раз регэксп придется прогнать по выражению с 100500 скобок.

Answer (score 1):

Если нет возможности перевести столько формул автоматически, то почему бы просто не найти такое же решение уже реализованное кем-нибудь другим?
Судя по тегам вопроса, решение на С++ тоже устроит.

[Решение уравнений 3-й и 4-й степеней.](http://esman.su/x4x3.html)